# Is std::function supported in the NDK?

Tags: android-ndk

I'm using NDK version r9b, and I think I added everything I needed for c++11 support in my application.mk file.  I don't get any complaints from eclipse when I include functional but when I try to use std::function it states:

Symbol 'function' could not be resolved

This is my android.mk file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
CPP_CORE := $(abspath $(call my-dir)/../../common)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := game
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -Wall -Wextra
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ApplicationEngine.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += jni.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += ../../common/Log.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += ../../common/MessageQueue.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := glwrapper.h
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(CPP_CORE) 
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lGLESv2
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -D__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -std=gnu++11
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

and my application.mk file:

```
APP_PLATFORM := android-10
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_STL:= gnustl_static
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.8
APP_CPPFLAGS := -fexceptions -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++
```

If anyone knows whether std::function is supported or not or sees me doing something wrong in a mk file I would appreciate the help.

Comment: Is it an error in Eclipse or is it a compile error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that "-stdlib=libc++" in APP_CPPFLAGS is invalid.  Once I removed that I was able to compile and use std::function without any problems.